# How do I pre-wire for in-ceiling speakers and give a clean finished look without installing speakers for several months?

Tags: speakers

I am building a new home and I would like to pre-wire for in-ceiling speakers. I have seen in some newer homes small plastic plugs in the ceiling where the wire is located. This allows the home owner to install the speakers at a later date, while still providing a nice clean finished look without a large cover; the plug is about the size of a silver dollar.

Does anyone know what these plugs are called and where I can purchase something like this?

Comment: Why not just tape the wires to the joists near where the speakers will be, and just drywall over it. When you're ready to install the speakers, cut the holes and grab the wires out from where they are waiting?

Comment: I would rather not have to keep a log on where the wires are. This gives easy access to the wires for mounting speakers later, but keeps a clean finished look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [low voltage boxes](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-1-Gang-Low-Voltage-Old-Work-Boxes-6-Pack-SC100RR-CP/202077426#.UgA095KKK8A) used for stereo equipment that may suit.

[image: low voltage box]

These can be covered by blank plates that are then painted to match the ceiling. When you are ready, remove the cover and either attach the device and wire through the box or cut a larger hole for the device.

As an Alternative, you could use a [bushing](http://www.homedepot.com/p/CE-TECH-Coaxial-Cable-Feed-Through-Bushing-White-COAXIAL-FEEDTHRU-BUSHING-WHITE/203717842#.UgA3XJKKK8A) like this, and wedge/glue the wires inside the tube

[image: bushing]

Then you can fill the center hole with taping compound or spackle. When you are ready, pull the bushing down with the wires attached.

Comment: Thanks for the bushing idea, that is the kind of "plug" I have been looking for. I like the small form factor that will allow for an array of options—such as mounting a speaker to the ceiling or going with in-ceiling speakers and cutting a larger hole—without needing as large a hole as a low-voltage box.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing in-ceiling speakers, you can generally get away with just stapling the cable to the joists where you are going to put the speaker. Take good pictures and measurements, and the just cut the hole you need and the wire will be there. It's a bit more complex if you have insulation; there in-ceiling speaker boxes you could put in ahead of time.

If you might use surface-mount speakers, the solution bib gave is better.